# WinUI 3 app crashed when deployed to the store

Tags: winui-3

I have a WinUI 3 App that recently crashed when I install it via the Windows Store. Funny enough I can build it in release mode and publish it locally and sideload and both works without crashing on startup.
The error message in the windows error logs is this:

```
.NET Version: 6.0.10
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)
   at MoneyFox.Win.Program.XamlCheckProcessRequirements()
   at MoneyFox.Win.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

The build is created via Azure DevOps and I run the app on Windows 11.
Is there any way to get more information about what actually is wrong here?

Comment: Might be related to this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6735) in the GitHub repo.

Comment: Since I deploy my app to the store I think it goes under packaged. As far as I can see this issue only relates to unpackaged apps.

Comment: I wonder if the issue is due to an issue with vs version installed on the agent. When I create a release locally and publish it manually it works as expected.

Comment: Looks like Windows App Sdk runtime is not installed, or at least not the right version.  Not sure how you can include it in the installation in the Store when unpackaged.

Comment: The app is deployed via the store and built via a package project, so it should be packaged. The issue occurs on my dev computer as well, which should have all sdk's installed.

Comment: @NPadrutt, try to compile and package the project as a 64-bit app (or 32-bit, if you do that already).  For one of my pet projects I have an issue on one of my machines, where only the 64-bit build will run.  The 32-bit build gives the same error.  No time to dig into it yet. :-(

Comment: I think I "found" the issue. I reverted my build pipeline back to using the NuGetCommand instead of the DotNetCoreCLI Task to restore Nugets. With that it works again. quite weird.  But by accident I was already building via x654. Thanks for all the inputs.